# Jmeter-Sql server database windows authentication issue.Getting following response in result tree

Tags: jmeter, sql-server-2016, jmeter-5.0

> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The
>   TCP/IP connection to the host 10.200.20.200, port 1111 has failed.
>   Error: "Connection refused: no further information. Verify the
>   connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is
>   running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make
>   sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a
>   firewall.".)

Used JDBC config and jdbc request sampler

Comment: Hi selim,port is 1433 only..i had just modified in the question...ip and port. All the 3 points which mentioned has been tired already. The database server is encrypted

Answer (score 0):

1. Your port `1111` looks suspicious, [default port for MS SQL Server is `1433`](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml). Double check TCP port(s) in SQL Server configuration:

   [image]
2. [SQL Server JDBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) assumes that TCP/IP transport is enabled in the SQL server so make sure that this is the case:

   [image]
3. If you plan to use Windows authentication make sure to have:

   - `Integrated Security=true;` stanza in your JDBC URL
     [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax)
   - `sqljdbc_auth.dll` file must be in [`java.library.path`](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Windows.asp)

Check out [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter/) article to get familiarized with databases load testing with JMeter concept.